# Help identifying a female power plug (500 V - 16/25 A AC - 3 pins - France)

Tags: power, identification, plug

Can you tell me what kind of plug this is? I suppose it's from the 60's but I am absolutely not sure; it may well be more recent.

Are there adapters to allow connecting regular 220 V devices to it (safely)?

The nearest thing I found is [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=adaptateur%20parking%2016%2025a%20500v&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkjsehsJv5AhWQhM4BHUUpA9MQBSgAegQIARA4&biw=2560&bih=1259&dpr=1), but it does not seem to be exactly the same.
It says 250 V where this one is marked 500 V.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Kind of plug for standard 220 V (16 A?) devices:

[image]

[Here another sample](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/fiches-secteurs/7001075?cm_mmc=FR-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_FR_FR_Connecteurs_Whoop-_-(FR:Whoop!)%20Fiches%20secteurs-_-7001075&matchtype=&pla-340748718145&gclid=CjwKCAjw9NeXBhAMEiwAbaY4lk3SvFlJ0ywTDt60bSXm18z5dCkUF3ytALeEQ-hepZnUyPQHw9vrexoCAGgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

**EDIT : Added measures of the plug**

Comment: I don't know anything about French standards, but I did look this up on a couple sites and the outlet you show is seemingly NOT a French standard outlet.  It looks alot like some outlets used in India and South Africa.   https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/   If you can not find a compatible plug, perhaps what you have is a unicorn and you probably should consider to replace the whole outlet with something modern.   That kinda looks like something that woulda been installed in the 1940's.

Comment: Add...   Don't plug in ANY 220V device until you determine (with a voltmeter) that this outlet is actually 220V and not 500V.   The hazard is obvious if you get it wrong (and if it's not obvious, it will be soon as you plug it in....)

Comment: @KyleB: Thank you. Don't worry, I wasn't planning to connect something to it without being sure :) And guessing that it is by default 500V.

Comment: @KyleB: Yes, I guess it's an old outlet, probably from the 60's but really not sure.

Comment: Even 1960's is 60 years old  ;)    I'm just guessing at the age based on the design.   Maybe the best move you have is find the oldest local electrician you can and ask him/her for advice.

Comment: Blurb from this site: https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/French_classic-3hd.html
regarding French power sockets:

"Some models were probably not nationwide used on a large scale, but mainly appliance specific in workshops."

It seems at least possible that your socket is a proprietary configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an old version of this *Italian style* IEC60309 socket.

Being blue means 230V.

[image]

It's hard to be sure though, dimensions matter.

Comment: For sure. I'll try to get the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what kind of plug is this? I suppose it's from the 60's but absolutely not sure. May be more recent.

That may be an old version of industrial circular connectors introduced in the 1960s, based on the CEE 17 standard that was adopted in the UK as BS 4343, and is presently the IEC 60309 standard.

Mennekes Elektrotechnik GmbH & Co. KG was involved in the manufacture of such connectors more than fifty years ago and continue to do so as Mennekes Elektrotechnik Sachsen GmbH.

[*IEC 60309 - courtesy Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309)